# System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations MethodAccessException in Automated Controller Unit Test, MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, testing, automated-tests, data-annotations

First of all I'd like to say that I wouldn't doubt if this is a configuration error, because it's only happening on our CI build server and not on anyone's local development machine. So if anyone has a seemingly obvious configuration suggestion please feel free to point it out, my team doesn't configure the build server so there could be something simply not set up correctly.

I'm running into an issue with one of my automated tests, I'm having this issue in any test that involves the (System.ComponentModel.)DataAnnotations on the Entity that is being used. It seems to only occur with any test that involves the Controller calling TryUpdateModel.

Before I provide the entire error message, here’s a list of some of the things we’ve already tried:

- Adding the main MVC assemblies to the “fullTrustAssemblies” section of the app.config of the Test project
- Adding the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations assembly to the “partialTrustVisibleAssemblies” section of the app.config of the Test project
- Adding the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations assembly to the AppDomainSetup PartialTrustVisibleAssemblies in code
- Trying to use ReflectionPermission.Demand to see if there was a problem with permissions
- Ensuring that .NET Framework 4 and MVC3 were installed on the machine
- Checking for the registry key(s) [talked about in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397854.aspx)

Here's the full error:

```
Test method qTrade.UnitTests.Web.Controllers.Maintenance.TypeLookupControllerTest.CreatePostSaveInvalidEntityAndModelState threw exception: 
System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.Mvc.TypeDescriptorHelper.Get(System.Type)' to access security critical method 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider..ctor(System.Type)' failed.

Assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is a conditionally APTCA assembly which is not enabled in the current AppDomain.  To enable this assembly to be used by partial trust or security transparent code, please add assembly name 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B5FC90E7027F67871E773A8FDE8938C81DD402BA65B9201D60593E96C492651E889CC13F1415EBB53FAC1131AE0BD333C5EE6021672D9718EA31A8AEBD0DA0072F25D87DBA6FC90FFD598ED4DA35E44C398C454307E8E33B8426143DAEC9F596836F97C8F74750E5975C64E2189F45DEF46B2A2B1247ADC3652BF5C308055DA9' to the the PartialTrustVisibleAssemblies list when creating the AppDomain

Test method qTrade.UnitTests.Web.Controllers.Maintenance.TypeLookupControllerTest.CreatePostSaveInvalidEntityAndModelState threw exception: 
System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'System.Web.Mvc.TypeDescriptorHelper.Get(System.Type)' to access security critical method 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider..ctor(System.Type)' failed.

Assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is a conditionally APTCA assembly which is not enabled in the current AppDomain.  To enable this assembly to be used by partial trust or security transparent code, please add assembly name 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B5FC90E7027F67871E773A8FDE8938C81DD402BA65B9201D60593E96C492651E889CC13F1415EBB53FAC1131AE0BD333C5EE6021672D9718EA31A8AEBD0DA0072F25D87DBA6FC90FFD598ED4DA35E44C398C454307E8E33B8426143DAEC9F596836F97C8F74750E5975C64E2189F45DEF46B2A2B1247ADC3652BF5C308055DA9' to the the PartialTrustVisibleAssemblies list when creating the AppDomain.<br>    at System.Web.Mvc.TypeDescriptorHelper.Get(Type type)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.GetBinderFromAttributes(Type type, Func`1 errorMessageAccessor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinderDictionary.GetBinder(Type modelType, IModelBinder fallbackBinder)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinderDictionary.GetBinder(Type modelType, Boolean fallbackToDefault)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.TryUpdateModel[TModel](TModel model, String prefix, String[] includeProperties, String[] excludeProperties, IValueProvider valueProvider)
   at qTrade.UI.Web.Controllers.Maintenance.TypeLookupController.Create(FormCollection collection) in d:\cibuild\qTrade\qTradeCI\Sources\source\UI\qTrade.UI.Web\Controllers\Maintenance\TypeLookupController.cs:line 55
   at qTrade.UnitTests.Web.Controllers.Maintenance.TypeLookupControllerTest.CreatePostSaveInvalidEntityAndModelState() in d:\cibuild\qTrade\qTradeCI\Sources\source\Tests\qTrade.UnitTests\Web\Controllers\Maintenance\TypeLookupControllerTest.cs:line 178
   at System.Web.Mvc.TypeDescriptorHelper.Get(Type type)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.GetBinderFromAttributes(Type type, Func`1 errorMessageAccessor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinderDictionary.GetBinder(Type modelType, IModelBinder fallbackBinder)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinderDictionary.GetBinder(Type modelType, Boolean fallbackToDefault)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.TryUpdateModel[TModel](TModel model, String prefix, String[] includeProperties, String[] excludeProperties, IValueProvider valueProvider)
   at qTrade.UI.Web.Controllers.Maintenance.TypeLookupController.Create(FormCollection collection) in d:\cibuild\qTrade\qTradeCI\Sources\source\UI\qTrade.UI.Web\Controllers\Maintenance\TypeLookupController.cs:line 55
   at qTrade.UnitTests.Web.Controllers.Maintenance.TypeLookupControllerTest.CreatePostSaveInvalidEntityAndModelState() in d:\cibuild\qTrade\qTradeCI\Sources\source\Tests\qTrade.UnitTests\Web\Controllers\Maintenance\TypeLookupControllerTest.cs:line 178
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**I Fixed the problem !**

This is a combination of running in Medium Trust, having MVC installed in the GAC and using "dynamic" (or a shape) as a ViewModel. Only (and only if) these 3 conditions are true you run into this error. The solution is to change your controller code: instead of returning "View(model)", return "View((object)model)".